# How to change db migration order in Sequelize Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm getting below error when I'm trying to execute `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate`

```
ERROR: Failed to open the referenced table 'Companies'
```

I feel this is coming because I generated the user model before the company model. I mean, first, I have generated the user, then I have generated company and I have added a reference like the user belongsTo company.

```
 Company.hasMany(models.User, {
      as: 'users',
      foreignKey: 'compId'
    });

 User.belongsTo(models.Company, {
      as:'company',
      foreignKey:'compId'
    })
```

Do anyone knows how to resolve that

Comment: they go through the order of the files, so, add date to the name of the files, for example: `202006031828` as the date of file creation, then you know that would run prior of the next one if you add "1 minute"

Comment: @balexandre then I should have to order the all the files as the relationships

Answer (score -1):

I changed files names date order with 1 minute difference to each file based on my relationships , it worked for me